# Error in iOS 8 "The network connection was lost.”

Tags: ios, objective-c

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x7ba8e5b0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a6957e0 "The network connection was lost."}

When I am trying to access a URL which is on http:// so why it is giving me the error of "The Network connection was lost" as my network connection is working fine.Is there any way to tackle it?.And I tried many solutions provided by stack overflow but no success please help me.

Comment: simulator in not network availbale

Comment: Trying to reboot simulator

Comment: I am testing on iOS device and tried to reboot device.

Comment: what exact version of iOS?

Comment: Try opening a web page in safari in the simulator. Then you can know whether network is available in Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS Simulator, Select "Reset Content and Settings ..." from top menu. It will fixed that issue.